# Remove duplicates values when all values are the same

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using SQL workbench/J connecting to amazon redshift.

I have the following data in a table (there are more columns that need to be kept but are all the exact same values for each unique claim_id regardless of line number):

```
Member ID   |   Claim_ID   |   Line_Number   |
   1             100             1
   1             100             2
   1             100             1
   1             100             2
   2             101             13
   2             101             13
   2             101             13
   2             101             13
   3             102             12
   3             102             12
   1             103             2
   1             103             2
```

I want it to become the following which will remove any duplicates based on claim_id (it does not matter which line number is kept):

```
Member ID   |   Claim_ID   |   Line_Number   |
   1             100             1
   2             101             13
   3             102             12
   1             103             2
```

I have tried the following:

```
select er_main.member_id, er_main.claim_id, er_main.line_number, 
temp.claim_id, temp.line_number
from OK_ER_30 er_main
inner join (
    select row_number() over (partition by claim_id order by line_number desc) as seqnum    
    from 
      OK_ER_30 temp) temp
  ON er_main.claim_id = temp.claim_id and seqnum = 1
  Order by er_main.claim_id, temp.line_number
```

and this:

```
select * from ok_er_30
where claim_id in
(select distinct claim_id
from ok_er_30
group by claim_id
)
order by claim_id desc
```

I have checked many other ways of pulling only one row per distinct claim_id but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select Member_ID,Claim_ID,max(Line_Number) group by Member_ID,Claim_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select Distant(Member_ID,Claim_ID,max(Line_Number)) group by Member_ID,Claim_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code.

```
declare @OK_ER_30 table(Member_ID int, Claim_ID int, Line_Number int);

insert @OK_ER_30 values
  (1, 100, 1),
  (1, 100, 2),
  (1, 100, 1),
  (1, 100, 2),
  (2, 101, 13),
  (2, 101, 13),
  (2, 101, 13),
  (2, 101, 13),
  (3, 102, 12),
  (3, 102, 12),
  (1, 103, 2),
  (1, 103, 2);

with
  t as(
    select *, row_number() over(
      partition by Member_ID, Claim_ID order by (select 0)
    ) rn
    from @OK_ER_30
  )
delete from t where rn > 1;

select * from @OK_ER_30;
```